# Is it possible to update primary key in clickhouse using MergeTree engine?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to update primary key in simple table.

When i execute the query like this:

```
alter table test update id = 2 where id = 1;
```

I see the message:

```
Cannot UPDATE key column `id`
```

Is there any workarounds about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. As a workaround you need to change primary key to different columns that don't need updating. This cannot be done in place, so you need to create new table with proper primary key and then migrate data via INSERT+SELECT or [clickhouse-copier](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/utils/clickhouse-copier/).